# Code works on site, not on CodePen: Uncaught error '<'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, codepen

My code works on my site, but not on CodePen. When I tried copying the code from Visual Studio Code to CodePen, this error appears:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

This is the link to my codePen: https://codepen.io/sherlockieee/pen/ExPXKgJ

Here is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import marked from "marked";

// ALLOWS LINE BREAKS WITH RETURN BUTTON
marked.setOptions({
  breaks: true,
});

const renderer = new marked.Renderer();
renderer.link = function (href, title, text) {
  return `<a target="_blank" href="${href}">${text}</a>`;
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      markdown: placeholder,
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      markdown: e.target.value,
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container">
          <h1> Markdown Preview </h1>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="editor-box col">
              <h2>Editor View</h2>
              <textarea onChange={this.handleChange} id="editor">
                {placeholder}
              </textarea>
            </div>

            <div className="preview-box col">
              <h2>Preview </h2>
              <div
                id="preview"
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                  __html: marked(this.state.markdown, { renderer: renderer }),
                }}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const placeholder = `# Welcome to my React Markdown Previewer 


`;

export default App;
```

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: @ArthurRubens Did you see it render? When I opened it it's not there but the minute I clicked on the console/ website it appears

Comment: @HaTran Have you tried my answer?

Comment: @hev1 I tried it and it didn't work!

Comment: @HaTran Any errors in the console?

Comment: @ArthurRubens Browser? OS?

Comment: @ArthurRubens Did you happen to open the CodePen Console? There's a tab in the very lower left of the interface. The error doesn't necessarily appear in the browser, since CodePen intercepts calls to `console`.

Comment: Note that the links to CodePen on React's site all have their JavaScript preprocessed by Babel, which knows how to deal with JSX... They also all call `ReactDOM.render('<ComponentName/>', document.querySelector('someId'));`. See for example https://codepen.io/pen?&editable=true&editors=0010

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your Javascript inside a script tag with `type="text/jsx"`, as JSX is not valid Javascript.

```
<script type="text/jsx">
//..Your code
</script>
```